# Update BackgroundWorker to Task where method returns a value used to update UI

Tags: c#, winforms, task, backgroundworker

I have a number of projects where background threads are used to do long-running work, and a bool is used to flag if the thread is complete before the UI is updated from the long-running task (technique used in some old NET 3.5 projects). This is a frowned-upon approach, with BackgroundWorker or Task (preferred) being better.

I created a simple test project using BackgroundWorker (see  below) and it works, but I can't find a complete working example to do this using Task and every attempt I make either locks the UI or throws exceptions.  My question is how would I do this with Task?

Here is the code - it is just a Winforms project with one chart and two buttons:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider();

    private double[] data;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (chart1.Series.Count > 0) { chart1.Series.RemoveAt(0); }
        ((Button)sender).Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Please wait");
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            data = dataProvider.ReturnPlotData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show($"ERROR: {ex.StackTrace.ToString()}"); ; }
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled) { MessageBox.Show("BackgroundWorker task cancelled"); }
        else if (e.Error != null) { MessageBox.Show($"ERROR during task execution: {e.Error.StackTrace.ToString()}"); }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                UpdatePlot(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show($"ERROR: {ex.StackTrace.ToString()}"); ; }
        }
        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void UpdatePlot(double[] data)
    {
        chart1.Series.Add("Data");
        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) { chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(data[i]); }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { while (chart1.Series.Count > 0) { chart1.Series.RemoveAt(0); } }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { MessageBox.Show("I'm doing something else now..."); }
}

internal class DataProvider
{
    public double[] ReturnPlotData()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    }
}
```

here's one attempt at conversion.  This gives me a type conversion error (Task vs Task double[] ):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider();

    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { while (chart1.Series.Count > 0) { chart1.Series.RemoveAt(0); } }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<double[]> task = Task.Run(() => 
        {
            dataProvider.ReturnPlotData();
        }).ContinueWith(t => UpdatePlot(task.Result));
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { MessageBox.Show("I'm doing something else now..."); }

    private void UpdatePlot(double[] data)
    {
        chart1.Series.Add("Data");
        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) { chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(data[i]); }
    }
}

internal class DataProvider
{
    public double[] ReturnPlotData()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your efforts to make it Task based? Then we have a starting point to work from, even if they fail for now.

Comment: _"This gives me a type conversion error (Task vs Task double[] )"_ -- where do you get that error? What does the error say, _exactly_? Also, note that you should make `private async void button1_Click(...)`, then instead of using `ContinueWith()` explicitly, you can do `UpdatePlot(await Task.Run(dataProvider.ReturnPlotData));` instead. (Indeed, now I see where you'd get that error...the `ContinueWith()` method returns a `Task`...which you don't even need, so the `task` variable can be omitted entirely. But use `async`/`await` like I said anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted can be made to work by simplifying the code:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdatePlot(await Task.Run((Func<double[]>)dataProvider.ReturnPlotData));
}
```

You were getting the error because `ContinueWith()` returns a `Task` object. The original `Task<double[]>` object is what's passed to your `ContinueWith()` delegate. You don't need the `Task` returned from `ContinueWith()`, so you could just omit the `task` variable altogether (and thus the incompatible assignment).

But, you shouldn't be using `ContinueWith()` anyway. That's what `await` is for.

Comment: Sorry...lacking a [mcve] I didn't bother to compile the proposed new code. You should be able to resolve the error by explicitly  casting the parameter (see edit above)

Comment: This solution works, so I accepted it..  I can't see how the code I provided isn't MCVe - I included the entire code except for the form designer and I described the design (1 chart and 2 buttons).

Comment: There is enough information in your question to provide an answer (obviously). But an MCVE would be compile-able strictly as-is. When I see stuff like `chart1`, things that would require that I guess how you've configured your program, I don't bother. It takes took much time, and I've no guarantee of getting it right. The question is certainly better than many, but it's not enough for me to spend time getting the IDE involved (especially for a relatively simple issue like this).